# Code of Symbols in HTML

Tags: html

I want to show the actually text/code of the symbol instead. For example, I want to show this "& # 1 4 0;" (without space) on my website but it only appears the symbol.

Comment: Use the <pre> tag

Comment: I want to show the code (&#140;) not the symbol.

Comment: Type the ampersand as a symbol: `&amp;#140;`

Comment: thank you for you answer! It works :D

Comment: Can you please post it as an answer ??? @Sevanteri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type the ampersand as a symbol: `&amp;#140;`

Comment: Sorry for the postpone. I just got home from school! Thank you by the way.